# "sharerDidCancel:" is called after first successful share when Facebook app is not installed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-share, facebook-sdk-4.x

I use a UIButton to share using Facebook's SDK 4.31.1. Once tapped, a share dialog is presented.

```
- (IBAction)btnSharePressed:(id)sender
{
    [self displayShareDialog];
}

- (void)displayShareDialog {
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [self getShareContent];

    if ([FacebookHandler isFacebookAppInstalled]) {
        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
    } else {
        FBSDKShareDialog * shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
        [shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser];
        [shareDialog setDelegate:self];
        [shareDialog setFromViewController:self];
        [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
        [shareDialog show];
    }
}

// Expects the URL of the scheme e.g. "fb://"
+ (BOOL)isFacebookAppInstalled {
    NSArray* fbSchemes = @[@"fbapi://",
                           @"fb-messenger-api://",
                           @"fbauth2://",
                           @"fbshareextension://"];
    BOOL isInstalled = false;

    for (NSString* fbScheme in fbSchemes) {
        isInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fbScheme]];
        if(isInstalled) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return isInstalled;
}
```

But when Facebook app is not installed, on every launch, on the first successful share the delegate method `sharerDidCancel:` is called and on any further successful share the correct delegate method `sharer:didCompleteWithResults:` is called.
I have correctly set the `FacebookDisplayName` and `FacebookId` in the `plist` file so it’s not about that.
I also tried switching `FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser` with `FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser` with no luck.

Can someone shed some light on why the `cancel` method is called first,  even though the share was completed successfully and why it is like that only after the first share?